# Enable gzip compression

Tags: performance

How I can Enable compression for the following URL:

Compressing https://hwrmedia.com.au/ could save 37.6KiB (82% reduction).

I'm checking it on (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fhwrmedia.com.au%2F&tab=desktop)

Please help!!!

Comment: Server setup questions normally should be asked on sister site ServerFault - https://serverfault.com/ . This site is for programming questions.  See [tour] and [ask]  then either  edit your question or delete it and ask at ServerFault.

Comment: For this you have to create a .htaccess file in root of the server. Then paste the code in this link https://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html

Comment: Its not working

Answer (score 1):

Which programming language do you use? If you are using Node.js and Express you can use a compression middleware to enable compression.

```
var app = express();
var compression = require('compression');
app.use(compression());
```

Another solution is to put a CDN in front of your page and enable compression there. Using cloudfront, compression can be enabled clicking a checkbox in the behaviour settings.